# Obtaining the address of a cell from a CSV file in C++

Tags: c++, csv, vector, file-processing

I have CSV file data in the following format:

```
Name, Quantity, Price
xyz, 30, 300
abc, 25, 200
```

Sample of data contained in CSV file:

| Name | Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 30 | 300 |
| abc | 25 | 200 |

I need to access specific cells of price and quantity for names that are known to me. I am thinking about storing row data in vectors and then accessing required cells but how can I obtain the cell address of the known names? Any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be better to show the raw data here instead of a formatted table.

Comment: `strtok()` comes to mind...

Comment: In general: If the data is simple (no embedded/escaped delimiters) you may be able to use regular expressions. If e.g. strings can contain cell delimiter characters then you must parse the data yourself; or maybe there is a CSV library?

Comment: Assuming you mean how to efficiently access this data once loaded into memory, store the entries and in a map keyed by name

Answer (score 0):

You have basically 2 tasks

1. Read and parse a csv file
2. Get the data base on a name

We will tackle one problem after the other. First, reading and parsing a csv file. There are really many many potential solutions for that. You will find tons of example here on SO. Let me show some of them to you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstring>
#include <forward_list>
#include <deque>

using Container = std::vector<std::string>;
std::regex delimiter{ "," };


int main() {

    // Some function to print the contents of an STL container
    auto print = [](const auto& container) -> void { std::copy(container.begin(), container.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::decay<decltype(*container.begin())>::type>(std::cout, " ")); std::cout << '\n'; };

    // Example 1:   Handcrafted -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };
        Container c{};

        // Search for comma, then take the part and add to the result
        for (size_t i{ 0U }, startpos{ 0U }; i <= stringToSplit.size(); ++i) {

            // So, if there is a comma or the end of the string
            if ((stringToSplit[i] == ',') || (i == (stringToSplit.size()))) {

                // Copy substring
                c.push_back(stringToSplit.substr(startpos, i - startpos));
                startpos = i + 1;
            }
        }
        print(c);
    }

    // Example 2:   Using very old strtok function ----------------------------------------------------------
    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };
        Container c{};

        // Split string into parts in a simple for loop
#pragma warning(suppress : 4996)
        for (char* token = std::strtok(const_cast<char*>(stringToSplit.data()), ","); token != nullptr; token = std::strtok(nullptr, ",")) {
            c.push_back(token);
        }

        print(c);
    }

    // Example 3:   Very often used std::getline with additional istringstream ------------------------------------------------
    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };
        Container c{};

        // Put string in an std::istringstream
        std::istringstream iss{ stringToSplit };

        // Extract string parts in simple for loop
        for (std::string part{}; std::getline(iss, part, ','); c.push_back(part))
            ;

        print(c);
    }

    // Example 4:   Most flexible iterator solution  ------------------------------------------------

    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };


        Container c(std::sregex_token_iterator(stringToSplit.begin(), stringToSplit.end(), delimiter, -1), {});
        //
        // Everything done already with range constructor. No additional code needed.
        //

        print(c);


        // Works also with other containers in the same way
        std::forward_list<std::string> c2(std::sregex_token_iterator(stringToSplit.begin(), stringToSplit.end(), delimiter, -1), {});

        print(c2);

        // And works with algorithms
        std::deque<std::string> c3{};
        std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(stringToSplit.begin(), stringToSplit.end(), delimiter, -1), {}, std::back_inserter(c3));

        print(c3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But, because of the simplicity of the input data, you can also use a different method, by taking advantage that the IO functions often return a reference to the stream for which they were called.

This means, if you write `std::cout << "Hello";` , then this expression will return a reference to `std::cout`. And, because of that, chained statements like `std::cout << "Hello" << " " << "World";` will be possible. What will happen here? First, because of operator associativity, we can rewrite this to:

```
(((std::cout << "Hello") << " ") << "World");
```

So, first `std::cout << "Hello"` will be performed. The result is a reference to `std::cout`.  So, now we would have something like:

```
((std::cout << " ") << "World");
```

Then `std::cout << " "` will be performed and we again get a reference to `std::cout`. Resulting in:

```
std::cout << "World";
```

---

We can take advantage of this know how and read and parse one csv line with:

```
char dummyForEatingTheComma;
std::getline(is >> std::ws, p.name, ',') >> p.quantity >> dummyForEatingTheComma >> p.price;
```

Oh, what's going on here?

First, `is >> std::ws` will be executed. This will read all leading white spaces in front of the text  (It will also eat the last trailing '\n' after having read the price with a formatted input function). And because, as mentioned above, a reference to the stream will be returned, we will have now something equivalent to:

```
std::getline(is, p.name, ',') >> p.quantity >> dummyForEatingTheComma >> p.price;
```

And with that, `std::getline` will read the name and eat the comma. And guess what, `std::getline` will return a reference to the stream. This result in something similar like:

```
is >> p.quantity >> dummyForEatingTheComma >> p.price;
```

This looks already very familar. And I will not drill down this further. We read the quantity, the comma (and throw it away) and then the price.

Good. Job done.

We put all this in a class called "Product". The data, and the extraction and inserter operator.

Then we need to think about about your requirement to access the quantity or the price via the product name.

In C++ we can use associative containers for that, like `std::map` or `std::unordered::map`. We will store all data (the "Product") in a `std::vector` and then create a `std::unordered_map` where we will associate the name with the index of the "Product" in the `std::vector`.

This is a similar aprroach like in data bases. We basically build an index over the "Product Name".

Of course there are many other possible solutions. Especially not so nice is the double storage of the name in the "Product"-vector and in the `std::unordered_map`. All this could also be solved with one map only.

Anyway, let's continue this way.

We will encapsulate all the above mentioned stuff in an additionaly class called "Inventory" and add a minimum set of methods.

And all this will then come down to something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

struct Product {

    // Properties of one product
    std::string name{};
    double quantity{};
    double price{};

    // Simple extraction operator
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Product& p) {
        char dummyForEatingTheComma;
        return std::getline(is >> std::ws, p.name, ',') >> p.quantity >> dummyForEatingTheComma >> p.price;
    }
    // Simple inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Product& p) {
        return os << "\n\nName:\t\t" << p.name << "\nQuantity:\t" << p.quantity << "\nPrice:\t\t" << p.price;
    }
};
struct Inventory {
    // Here we will store all products and the index for the product
    std::vector<Product> products{};                            
    std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int> index{};

    // Build a simple index based on the product name
    void buildIndex() {
        index.clear();
        for (unsigned int i{}; i < products.size(); ++i)
            index[products[i].name] = i;
    }
    // Get data based on index
    std::pair<double, double> getData(const std::string& name) {
        if (std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int>::const_iterator ix = index.find(name); ix != index.end())
            return { products[ix->second].quantity, products[ix->second].price };
        else
            return { {},{} };
    }
    // Simple extraction operator
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Inventory& i) {
        // Eat header and ignore it
        std::string header{}; std::getline(is, header);

        // Clear all product data and read new data
        i.products.clear();
        i.products = { std::istream_iterator<Product>(is), {} };
        // Build index
        i.buildIndex();
        return is;
    }
    // Simple inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Inventory& i) {
        std::copy(i.products.begin(), i.products.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Product>(os, "\n"));
        return os;
    }
};

// ENter here the name/path of your csv
const std::string csvFileName{"r:\\csv.txt"};

int main() {
    // Open the file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream ifs{ csvFileName }; ifs) {

        // Here we will store the inventory
        Inventory inventory{};

        // Read and parse the complete csv file
        ifs >> inventory;

        // All done already.
        // Show some debug output
        std::cout << "\n\n\nDebug output\nComplete Inventory:";
        
        // Complete inventory
        std::cout << inventory;

        // show demo data based in index
        const auto& [q1, p1] = inventory.getData("abc");
        std::cout << "\n\n\nFor name: " << "abc\t\tQuantity:\t" << q1 << "\tPrice:\t" << p1 << '\n';

        const auto& [q2, p2] = inventory.getData("xyz");
        std::cout << "For name: " << "xyz\t\tQuantity:\t" << q2 << "\tPrice:\t" << p2 << '\n';
       
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error: Could not open file '" << csvFileName << "' for reading.\n\n";
}
```

Caveat. It will not work for duplicated names . . .

Answer (score 0):

The CSV format is plain text and has nothing to do with Excel cells (and even less with addresses).

Read the file line by line and split the lines at the comma separators. Nothing really hard.

---

You can also solve this  in Excel using VBA calls, but this is a difficult task, and even more difficult to perform from C++.